# How to correctly implement a different version from a Base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a class that inherit from (lets say) `Base`. But there is a problem, `Base`does have an class which declaration is like this:

```
template<typename It> void getInfo(It begin, It end);
```

But in the second class `Inh` i concluded that this version of the class that take 2 iterators is not the best, so i decided that it has to be like this:

```
templtate<typename T> void getInfo(size_t where, const T& initial_value);//The class itself is a template that gets "T"
```

and the version inherited from `Base` must NEVER be used, so i decided to:

```
template<typename It> void getInfo(It begin, It end) = delete;
```

But as you can guess, when you use the class `Ihn` using `int` as type, like this:

```
Ihn<int> obj;
obj.getInfo(5, 1000);//Trying to get the deleted function!
```

It calls the deleted function because 5 and 1000 are the same type, and not `size_t`. Do you have any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like another case where inheritance is not the appropriate technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you don't need to mark the `getInfo` as `delete`. If you declare another `getInfo` in the derived class, it will *hide* the one from the base class. Then

```
Ihn<int> obj;
obj.getInfo(5, 1000); // would always try to call getInfo in the derived class
```

And you can still call the base version explicitly like

```
obj.Base::getInfo(...);
```

Comment: I believe this is called [*dominance*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#:~:text=dominance).

Comment: It is impossible to call the `Base` version? (which is what i need, because use of the `Base` version is undefined behavior)

Comment: @FranzKafka Yes but also no. `obj.getInfo(arg1, arg2)` will never call the `Base` version. But, you can always cast it: `static_cast<Base&>(obj).getInfo(arg1, arg2)` would call the `Base` version whether or not you have the `delete`d definition in the subclass. If it's defined in the base class it is *impossible* to prevent it from being called on subclass objects, and the code in the question doesn't stop the `Base` class version from being called (by a suitably stubborn programmer) either.

Comment: @FranzKafka You can call the base version explicitly like `obj.Base::getInfo(...);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a specific function depending on the arguments you pass it, then you might consider just ensuring that the arguments actually match.

So: `obj.getInfo((size_t) 5, 1000)`

If the compiler finds the right function than it doesn't matter whether any other functions with 'It' as arguments exist, are deleted or whatever, they'll just be ignored. Your compiler still calling the deleted function simply means it failed to assign your function call to your new function.